# LSTM fit_generator steps_per_epoch

Tags: machine-learning, keras, lstm

Because of the large data, I'm using fit_generator with a custom generator to train LSTM model.

I haven't used LSTM with fit_generator before, so I don't know whether my code is correct.

```
def generator_v2(trainDir,nb_classes,batch_size):
print('start generator')
classes = ["G11","G15","G17","G19","G32","G34","G48","G49"]
while 1:
    print('loop generator')
    for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(trainDir):
        for file in files:
            try:

                label = root.split("\\")[-1]
                label = classes.index(label)
                label = to_categorical(label,num_classes=nb_classes).reshape(1,nb_classes)
                df = pd.read_csv(root +"\\"+ file)
                batches = int(np.ceil(len(df) / batch_size))
                for i in range(0, batches):
                    x_batch = df[i * batch_size:min(len(df), i * batch_size + batch_size)].values
                    x_batch = x_batch.reshape(1, x_batch.shape[0], x_batch.shape[1])
                    yield x_batch, label

                del df

            except EOFError:
                print("error" + file)

trainDir = "data_diff_level2_statistics"
nb_classes = 8
batch_size = 128
MaxLen = 449    # each csv file has 449 rows,
batches = int(np.ceil(MaxLen / batch_size))
filesCount = sum([len(files) for r, d, files in os.walk(trainDir)])  # the number of all files

steps_per_epoch = batches*filesCount

model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(4,input_shape=(None,5)))
model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(nb_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adadelta',metrics=['acc'])

model.fit_generator(generator_v2(trainDir,nb_classes,batch_size),steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch, nb_epoch = 100, verbose=1)
```

Do I set the correct number of steps_per_epoch?

My all training data shape is : (230,449,5)

So, I set steps_per_epoch with 230 * (449/batch_size).

(449/batch_size) means I read a csv file 128 rows at a time.

Answer (score 1):

The argument  `steps_per_epoch` should be equal to the total number of samples (length of your training set) divided by batch_size(the same is available for `validation_steps`.

In your example, the length of the dataset is given by `dataset_length = number_of_csv_files * length_of_csv_file`.

Therefore, your code is correct since you have 230 * (449/batch_size), which is similar to what I have written above.

Comment: Thanks! I'm doing the contest which will be expired very soon so I hope someone can reply me immediately. Thank you!